# Passing a true/false value to a model used in a controller

Tags: html, asp.net, mvc, razor

This passes the value of true/false to model which I can use in my controller.

How can this be cleaned up?

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="inline-toggle">
        <label for="IsAuto">Auto <a href="#"><img class="smallInfo" src="/sites/dev-demo/mobile/assets/images/info@2x.png"></a>:</label>
        <select name="IsAuto" class="togglehidden" id="IsAuto" data-role="slider" data-hidden-id="#autohidden">
            <option value="false">No</option>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
        </select>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsAuto, new { id = "#IsAuto", value="#IsAuto" })
        <input type ="hidden" name ="autorel" id="autorel" value="@(Model.IsAuto = "#IsAuto".AsBool())" />
```

Answer (score 2):

None. However, it has several issues. Here it is, indented differently to avoid horizontal scroll:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="inline-toggle">
    <label for="IsAuto">Auto
        <a href="#">
            <img class="smallInfo" src="/sites/dev-demo/mobile/assets/images/info@2x.png">
        </a>:
    </label>
    <select name="IsAuto"
            class="togglehidden"
            id="IsAuto"
            data-role="slider"
            data-hidden-id="#autohidden">
        <option value="false">No</option>
        <option value="true">Yes</option>
    </select>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsAuto, new { id = "#IsAuto", value="#IsAuto" })
    <input
        type ="hidden"
        name ="autorel"
        id="autorel"
        value="@(Model.IsAuto = "#IsAuto".AsBool())" />
```

1. Where is the closing tag for `div`?
2. What do you use, XHTML or HTML5? In the first case, you should close `img`. In the second case, you shouldn't close the last `input`.
3. [`"#IsAuto".AsBool()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568994%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) always returns false, since `"#IsAuto"` is never equal to `"true"`.
4. Why are you assigning a value to a property of your model in a view in the last line? Maybe you expected `Model.IsAuto == ...`?
5. An `id` of the hidden field which starts by `#` is weird.
6. If you care about naming conventions, `m` is a poor name for a variable. Basically, any person who have never used ASP.NET MVC before wouldn't be able to know that it refers to a model.
7. Given the actual syntax for the hidden field, wouldn't it be easier to simply write it in plain HTML?